# Sublime Text 3 side bar icons

Tags: icons, sublimetext3

I've just installed ST3 on my High Sierra.

I wish to know how to enable icons for file types in my sidebar. I'will be using ReactJS, React-Native, Relay, etc. files.

Are those icons already included in ST3 ?

If not, what is the recommended icon package, where to grab it and how to install ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the **A File Icon** package.
The link is provided here: [A File Icon](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/A%20File%20Icon)

with full detailed instructions.
In case you don't have the package control installed here is the link to install it:
[Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)

Answer (score 2):

*open:* tool>command palette>
*type this:* Package Control: Install Package
*then type this:* A File Icon
**and you will get sidebar icons installed successfully**